# Растянуть элемент на всю высоту

Tags: html, css

Как растянуть элемент **на всю высоту** **не используя** height:100%?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Относительно окна :: 100vh

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Относительно окна :: 100%

```css
html, body, div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Относительно окна :: absolute / fixed

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Относительно контейнера :: absolute

```css
section {
  position: relative;

  min-height: 120px;
  margin: 1em;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```

## Относительно контейнера :: flex

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  
  min-height: 120px;
  margin: 1em;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```

## Относительно контейнера :: grid

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  
  min-height: 120px;
  margin: 1em;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```

Comment: справедливости ради, не сказано, что надо растянуть "на высоту окна", по этому 100vh - тут лишнее.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, ага, уточнил и добавил ещё grid.

Answer (score 1):

используй 
width:100%;

уверяю тебя, что что элемент растянется на всю ширину, и как видишь  без  height:100%

Answer (score 0):

```
.block{
   height: 100vh; /* 1vh = 1% от выстоты холста браузера*/
}
```

Это если относительно только окна браузера, тогда в "vh" Также если присвоить элементу `position: absolute;` или `position: fixed;`  можно и в процентах. Внутри блока тоже в процентах.

Comment: Что нового по сравнению с моим ответом?

Answer (score 0):

И еще вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('#block').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#block {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```