# Как сделать, чтоб ссылки занимали всю доступную высоту заголовка?

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте! Подскажите, как мне сделать, чтоб ссылки занимали всю доступную высоту хедера. Вёрстка

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E8BB49;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: none
  }

  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background: #403C3C;
  }

  .logo {
    font-size: 36px;
  }

  .categories {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .list-films {
    display: none;
  }

  .categories:hover > .list-films {
    display: block;
  }

  .input-search {
    background: #E8BB49;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .signin, .signup {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .img-telegram {
    width: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">KinoKings</a>
      </div>

      <div class="open-categories">
        <a href="#" class="categories">Категории кино</a>
        <nav class="list-films">
          <ul>
            <li> 
              <a href="#">Фильмы</a>
            </li>
            <li> 
              <a href="#">Сериалы</a>
            </li>
            <li> 
              <a href="#">Аниме</a>
            </li>
            <li> 
              <a href="#">Комедии</a>
            </li>
            <li> 
              <a href="#">Боёвики</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" class="input-search">
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="#" class="signin">Войти</a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="#" class="signup">Зарегистрироваться</a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="@/assets/telegram.svg" class="img-telegram">
      </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: нужно задать хедеру высоту, и потом ссылкам и всем его родителям (до хедера) сделать `height: 100%`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Растянуть элемент на всю высоту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712531/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: А после того как я задал 100% у меня блок ростянулся на всю высоту, но ссылка ушла немного вверх

Comment: Попробуйте выставить `display`: `table` у <header> (+ width: 100%, чтобы вернуть растягивание на ширину страницы), `table-row` у <div>, `table-cell` у `div > a`.